# Creating UDH for 7-bit concatenated SMS

Tags: java, string, header, sms, concatenation

I need to send concatenated SMS for which i split the message(which is more than 160 bytes) in small parts now i want to put one header in each part.header have 6 octets as follows

Field 1 (1 octet): Length of User Data Header, in this case 05.
Field 2 (1 octet): Information Element Identifier, equal to 00 (Concatenated short messages, 8-bit reference number)
Field 3 (1 octet): Length of the header, excluding the first two fields; equal to 03
Field 4 (1 octet): 00-FF, CSMS reference number, must be same for all the SMS parts in the CSMS
Field 5 (1 octet): 00-FF, total number of parts.
Field 6 (1 octet): 00-FF, this part's number in the sequence.

Example:
05 00 03 CC 02 01 [ message ] 
05 00 03 CC 02 02 [ message ]

Now the problem is i want to put these 6 octets in 7 septets and which need to decrements the size of an SMS message from 160 to 153 characters.How to convert these 6 octets in 7 septets.is there any coding avilable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really not that difficult.

The difference between a 7 bit number and an 8 bit number as that the 7 bit number has it's upper bit missing.

Given that your dealing directly with bytes I'm going to assume your doing this directly in PDU mode, esp since you do seem to know what your byte layout is.

to convert your 8 bit bytes into 7 bits you just need to get rid of the upper bit EG:

if you have

```
05 00 03 CC
```

then in 8 bit you have

```
00000101 00000000 00000011 11001100
```

technically to truncate these to 7 bit it's just a matter of stripping off the top bit as follows

```
0000101 0000000 0000011 1001100
```

However, you WILL have a problem with your values above, and that's with your

```
CC
```

Value.  If you strip the top bit from that, you'll effectively change it to a value of

```
4C
```

which may cause your SMS system to interprete the details incorrectly

It's for this reason that in pretty much all cases when dealing directly with the binary that you use an 8 bit send, so that you preserve the values.

However, going ahead with the example should you wish to try it, the next step is to then concatenate the 7 bit values together as follows

```
0000101000000000000111001100
```

You then need to divide this by 8 (The transmission medium is still 8 bit, even if the coding is not)

```
00001010 00000000 00011100 1100
```

Then pad the final byte out to 8 bits so that the transmission is an even number

```
00001010 00000000 00011100 1100xxxx
```

The xxxx will be either all 1's or all 0's depending on what your using to send the bytes, if it's an AT command, then likley it'll be all 0's so your 7 bit encoding will end up being

```
0A 00 1C C0
```

Which as you can see hasn't saved you any bytes.

A 7 bit encoding only reliably works if your using the GSM alphabet (you get that by setting the correct DCS values) how you set this again depends on what your using to send the SMS in the first place.

Most HTTP providers for example provide some sort of switch/flag to do this.

Comment: Not like that Shawty Pls see my next question.

Comment: So are you actually trying to make the entire UDH 7 Bit, or the payload?  If the former, then the way we used to do it at orange was just to start the actual SMS  where the 4 xxxx bits are above, effectively shortening the message by 4 bits, be aware though, this didn't always work though. Compress the message itself by all means but if possible you should keep the udh at 8 bits.

Comment: what should i do?? shall i keep header 8 bit.then it will be 8*6=48bit but i want it as 49 bit.

Comment: It's a trade off, and it depends heavily on how your sending it.  As for your comment about it being 48 and you want 49, well in that case you just need to add an extra bit in the output like so - UDH + x + Payload.  You will need to shift everything after the extra bit left by 7 places though. Out of interest, exactly how are you sending your SMS?

Comment: Please refer This link.you will get how i am sending SMS.[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27480294/tryng-to-send-concatenated-sms-with-udh-but-getting-error-sms-too-long)

Comment: That doesn't tell me anything except your using Java! Are you using J2EE and send this via SMPP, or are you using J2ME and sending this from a device application?  Based on your other question, it seems to me that you've already solved the 7 bit problem, because your other question clearly shows your encoding the message using the 7 bit GSM alphabet.  As I said previously, your User Data Header is 8 bit for a reason, and that's because it needs the full 8 bits to represent all the values it needs.

Comment: I am using this specification for creating SMS [link](http://www.advox.se/download/protocols/EMI_UCP.pdf) in that operation 51 i am using,but getting error message too long.

Comment: Ok, so your talking directly to a custom SMSC service (Quote from the manual: "The interface is based on the ERMES UCP (Universal Computer
Protocol) with some SMSC-specific extensions") Unfortunately, I only have experience with Nokia based SMSC's and then only those that use the industry standard SMPP protocol.  The message "too long" tell's me that the payload your trying to send is too big for one message, in which case you'll need to consult the relevant sections in that API guide you linked me too, to tell you how to send your message in 2 parts using concatenation.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't help you any further with that because I'm not familiar with the SMSC and protocol your having to use, the guide will explain it to you, you'll just need to read it all thoroughly.